# How to pass value of variable into another text file?

Tags: python

I have text files which have sql queries.After running one file "tb_exec_ns_call_pln.txt" i'm getting two dates like- 2018-12-29 , 
2019-03-29.

i just want to pass these dates in other text file (tb_exec_ns_call_actvty.txt) using python. the text file contain the below query-

```
SELECT a.nm as cycle_nm, 
a.start_dt as cycle_start_dt, 
a.end_dt as cycle_end_dt, 
a.terr as territory,sales_drctn, 
x_rating1,
c.jnj_id as jnj_id,
c.prsn_first_nm,
c.prsn_last_nm, 
plnnd_calls as rep_goal
FROM eureka.cycle_plan a, eureka.cycle_plan_trgt b, eureka.acct c
WHERE 
a.id = b.cycle_plan 
and b.acct = c.id 
and b.del_flg = 'N'
***and start_dt >= '2018-12-29'***
***and end_dt <= '2019-03-29'***
and substring(a.terr,1,6) in ('106-KS','106-PI','106-VO') 
and a.status = 'In_Progress_vod'
and a.del_flg = 'N'
and c.del_flg = 'N' and plnnd_calls > 0
```

i have written python script also.. Please guide me how to pass the value.

```
path = "D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/tb_exec_ns_call_pln.txt"

sql_query_file = open(path, 'r')
sql_query1 = sql_query_file.read()
cur.execute(sql_query1)
res = cur.fetchall()
print(res)
print(type(res))
for val in res:
    print(val[1])
    print(val[2])
```

Comment: Is the intention to just write the values in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to have a string variable hardcoded in to `tb_exec_ns_call_actvty.txt` and then use `str.replace` to fill in the required info.

**Ex:**

```
SELECT a.nm as cycle_nm, 
a.start_dt as cycle_start_dt, 
a.end_dt as cycle_end_dt, 
a.terr as territory,sales_drctn, 
x_rating1,
c.jnj_id as jnj_id,
c.prsn_first_nm,
c.prsn_last_nm, 
plnnd_calls as rep_goal
FROM eureka.cycle_plan a, eureka.cycle_plan_trgt b, eureka.acct c
WHERE 
a.id = b.cycle_plan 
and b.acct = c.id 
and b.del_flg = 'N'
and start_dt >= 'START_DT'
and end_dt <= 'END_DT'
and substring(a.terr,1,6) in ('106-KS','106-PI','106-VO') 
and a.status = 'In_Progress_vod'
and a.del_flg = 'N'
and c.del_flg = 'N' and plnnd_calls > 0
```

**InCode:**

```
path = "D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/tb_exec_ns_call_pln.txt"

with open(path) as sql_query_file:
    sql_query1 = sql_query_file.read()
    sql_query1 = sql_query1.replace("START_DT", '2018-12-29').replace("END_DT", '2019-03-29')

cur.execute(sql_query1)
res = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: I would suggest embedding the query text in as a variable defined as a  triple-quoted `"""` string literal _in the script itself_ to avoid having to deal with reading an external file (although having that way might be preferable in some circumstances).